# Is there a way to dynamically re-use children of grid view in python flet same way as you can do that for android recycle view using an adapter?

Tags: flet

I want to implement a feed preview using grid view in flet python flutter bindings. Since the amount of data available on a server is much larger then it's sensible to hold in memory (especially with a child view per data item) I would like to re-use same n children of grid layout in the same way it can be done for recycle view in android sdk. This way not only I would be able to get away with using less child views then data items in memory but also facilitate on-demand download from the server.

With that said, I never used flet before and [example](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/gridview/) on the docs webpage seem to imply that only way to use grid view out of the box is to extend it's content with more children.

I definetly can try to implement my own data adapter class as as far as I understand, scrolling animation, on scroll callback, and children access all can be exposed, but given that this is my first non-personal project I would like to avoid writing my own code as much as I can not to introduce unnecessary bugs or poor decisions. Since data adapter is a fairly common pattern my guess is it already exists in flet, but I dont know under what name or in which module.

I hope someone can clarify for me whether flet has functionality similar to recycle view adapters from android sdk which can be used for the grid view or should I write my own?

Gratitude in advance.